# Proof of resonance giving a valid solution for an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

During a differential equations class, we were given the example:
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} -6\frac{dy}{dx} + 9y  = 10e^{3x}$.
Solving the auxiliary equation gives: $(Ax+B)e^{3x}$.

When finding a value for the particular solution, we picked y = $Cx^2e^{3x}$, so $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2Cxe^{3x} + 3Cx^2e^{3x}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2Ce^{3x} + 12Cxe^{3x} + 9Cx^2e^{3x}$.

Substituting these in gives us: $e^{3x}(2C + 12Cx + 9Cx^2 - 12Cx + 18Cx^2 +9Cx^2)=10e^{3x}$. By dividing through by $e^{3x}$ and canceling out like terms, we just get $C = 5$.

My question is is there a proof for why we have to multiply $Ce^{3x}$ by $x^2$? I understand that without doing so, some coefficients cancel out and we get contradictions. I also understand that it's because in the RHS, the $e^{3x}$ is contained twice in the solution to the complementary function. I'm more looking for a proof of why resonance gives a valid solution, if the proof exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint,

Since the $p(x)=10e^{3x}$ , particular solution in the form of $(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{3x}$
as auxiliary equation already gives $(A'x+B')e^{3x}$ but you dont need to consider the part $(A+Bx)e^{3x}$ in the particular solution because it is already in the auxiliary equation so particular solution in the form of $Cx^2e^{3x}$.

Even if you assume a particular solution in the form of $(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{3x}$
nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back and consider the initial homogeneous equation, namely $y'' - 6y' + 9y = 0$. Its characteristic polynomial is given by $r^2 - 6r + 9 = (r-3)^2$, which possesses a double root. In consequence, the homogeneous solutions are given by $e^{3x}$, as expected, and $xe^{3x}$, because the "usual" second solution would be $e^{3x}$ too, which coincides with the first one.

Now, the particular solution is often constructed as an ansatz from the source term. Yet, in the present case, the source term on the RHS also coincides with the first homogeneous solution $e^{3x}$, so that you need to introduce a prefactor $x^2$ in order to produce a new contribution to the general solution $-$ otherwise, the particular ansatz would only modify the constants of integration in front of the homogeneous solutions.